# Unable to view entries in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

I'm currently using RecyclerView to display a set of images with text in a list oriented horizontally. The problems is after setting the adapter and notifying it of change in data, I do not see the grid being populated. I've previously used gridView with arrayAdapter without any problems. Am I missing something fundamental?

** Also, I went through the logcat but did not find anything unusual. But if you need to see it, let me know and I'll add it here **

I've set up my data and adapter in the following way:

Model : CastViewObject

```
public class CastViewObject {


    String castImageUrl;
    String castName;
    String castCharName;

    public CastViewObject(String castName, String castCharName, String castImageUrl) {
        this.castImageUrl = castImageUrl;
        this.castName = castName;
        this.castCharName = castCharName;
    }

    public String getCastImageUrl() {
        return castImageUrl;
    }

    public void setCastImageUrl(String castImageUrl) {
        this.castImageUrl = castImageUrl;
    }

    public String getCastCharName() {
        return castCharName;
    }

    public void setCastCharName(String castCharName) {
        this.castCharName = castCharName;
    }

    public String getCastName() {
        return castName;
    }

    public void setCastName(String castName) {
        this.castName = castName;
    }

}
```

Adapter : CastViewAdapter (extends RecyclerView.Adapter) - Showing only the overriden methods for now.

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView imageView;
    public TextView textView;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cast_image);
        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cast_name);
    }
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    mContext = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    View castView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.cast_item_layout,parent,false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(castView);
    return  viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CastViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final String LOG_TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
        CastViewObject castObject = castViewList.get(position);
        TextView textView = holder.textView;
        textView.setText(castObject.getCastName());

    Picasso
            .with(mContext)
            .load(castViewList.get(position).getCastImageUrl())
            .resize(500, 750)
            .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_image)
            .into(holder.imageView, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    count++;
                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error in loading images");
                }
            });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return castViewList.size();
}
```

Custom row: cast_item_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cast_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cast_name"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/title_background_color"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:textColor="@color/title_text_color"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

RecyclerView in fragment layout:

```
      <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/cast_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/movie_image_detail"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/movie_image_detail"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cast_divider"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:clickable="false" />
```

Here's how I set the adapter in `onCreateView` method:

```
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.cast_list_view);
    castAdapter = new CastViewAdapter(new ArrayList<CastViewObject>());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(castAdapter);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    requestMovieDetails();
```

.. and notify the adapter of the change in data:

```
    public void setCastView(List<CastViewObject> castViewList){
        castAdapter.setCastViewList(castViewList);
        castAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @karaokyo I'm working on it. Since I'm unable to localize the problem, it's hard to create one. I'll edit the post soon as I'm ready.

Comment: everything looks fine so far, how do you set Adapter to your RecyclerView?

Comment: For the future, please create an MCVE before posting your question. Are you still working on that? Because this still isn't enough to go on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// ---> ver3.
 public class TestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TestAdapter>.ViewHolder> {  

    // -----------> c).
    private ArrayList<ModelObject> personArray;
    private Context context;

    // -----------> d). Set up a custom adapter constructor to pass data into this adapter
    public TestAdapter(ArrayList<ModelObject> data, Context context) {

      // And link the constructor's params with your adapter's member vars.
      this.context = context;  // I use this context for any UI feedback (say a Toast'er':))
      this.personArray = data;
    }

    @Override
    public SpecAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        // -----------> b). create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.row_spec_view, parent, false);                               // This is where you actually should call your context from parent
                                                                                                                                                       // because the context is for each view (row) and the parent here
                                                                                 // is the ViewGroup parent (parameter) not for the whole adapter

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);                                                                         // Instantiate a viewholder from a view and return it
        return vh;                                                                                                                         // This process happens over and over again for each
                                                                                                                                               // row.
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SpecAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

      /* onBindViewHolder is used to inject data into your objects (TextViews, Buttons, etc.) */

      // ------------> e).
      holder.userName.setText(personArray.get(position).getUserName());                     // getUserName() is a getter from your model object you store on the data array
      holder.userIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.spec_icon);                                           // Say you have a class Person, this class needs a setUserName and a getUserName
                                                                                  // also, <personArray> is what your data_feeder would be (what I was asking
                                                                                  // earlier on SO). You have to pass to the adapter this List or Array from your HTTP
                                                                                                                                                                    // method.
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    // ----------> a). Custom ViewHolder
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView userName;   // you can add any type of objects you'd like to work with
        ImageView userIcon;  // at a row level

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

            // adjust your resource name to fit your own row's widgets 
            userName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_textview);    
            specIcon = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_spec_icon);


            v.setClickable(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You have to `setAdapter` after this line:</strike>

> recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

**UPDATE**:

You just assigned new object to `this.castViewList`, but your adapter is bound to the old object which is empty, so there is nothing to show in the `RecyclerView`.
You have to do something like this:

```
this.castViewList.clear();
this.castViewList.addAll(castViewList);
```

Comment: I had thought initially setting the adapter earlier was the problem. But apparently, the order does not really matter. I did refer to several tutorials like [this](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-RecyclerView) which do not differentiate between the two.

Comment: Oh, I just checked with code, my bad, I made a wrong assumption.
That's weird, everything looks fine though.
Can you show me body of this method: `castAdapter.setCastViewList(castViewList);`

Comment: setCastViewList is just a setter method : `this.castViewList = castViewList;`

Comment: Good point. Although `Recycler.Adapter` does not support add and clear items, let me change the RecyclerView's adapter reference and see if that helps. I'll comment here in a few mins.

Comment: I think this is true of a ListView, but not of a RecyclerView.

Comment: @LeoLink : I may have misunderstood what you said. But doesn't `notifyDataSetChanged` solve that problem that you mentioned?

Comment: @shark1608 yeah it does... can you post the whole simplified project?

Comment: Working on that. As @karaokyo suggested, it's better to create an MCVE. I'll update the post once I do

Answer (score 0):

As some already suggested, make sure you assign a layout to your view before you attach the adapter to your recyclerview. Otherwise, your view will most likely be blank.

Take a look at the example in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html):

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

    // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
    // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // use a linear layout manager
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    // specify an adapter (see also next example)
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(myDataset);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: Thanks but that does not solve the problem. So as long as the view layout is set using LayoutManager before the adapter is updated, the view should be inflated with the items. I did go through the documentation and several tutorials but there is no mention of a strict order.

Comment: " Once you have added a RecyclerView widget to your layout, obtain a handle to the object, connect it to a layout manager, and attach an adapter for the data to be displayed". That's the the suggested order. Also, I'm not sure how you populate your RecyclerViewAdapter. Could your show your custom adapter constructor's implementation? Looking at this: "castAdapter = new CastViewAdapter(new ArrayList<CastViewObject>());" I would expect your constructor to be more like castAdapter = new <your_adapter's_name>(List<Custom_Obj>, context);

Comment: You maybe right about the order, but doesn't really help in this situation. I do not pass the context to the constructor since I set the context of the adapter during the `onCreateViewHolder` method. So my constructor looks like this : `castAdapter = new CastViewAdapter(new ArrayList<CastViewObject>());`

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Let me make sure I understand you correctly (correct me if I'm wrong), so in the onCreateViewHolder method of your custom adapter you are instantiating its own context?

Comment: Yes, you can check the code pertaining to the adapter in my post.

Comment: @shark1608, the reason why we need a constructor is to establish environment data (where is being called or instantiated from). A context should be given by the environment used to create or generate that object (either your activity, or a fragment, etc.) The reason for this is because once your onCreateViewHolder gets hit all your class member variables are already defined and allocated. Furthermore, your onCreateViewHolder method gets called many times (based on the type of data feeder (either an array or a list), put a break-point on it. Also, who's feeding this adapter?

Comment: I understand what you mean. But what is the point of passing the context to the constructor if there is no default parent constructor that takes the context? Thanks for the explanation though, i've learnt quite a bit as the time has progressed. 
The adapter is notified in `setCastView` that you see in the post. The method is called after I get a response for my HTTPRequest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88435/discussion-between-nactus-and-shark1608).

Comment: I added a set of snippets that would hopefully help a bit to get your adapter working. I tried to attach it as an answer, but all the code formatting was way off, so I deleted it. This is the [link](http://codeshare.io/CwNZf)

Comment: It worked! I followed your example. Made some changes : 
1. Instantiate the adapter with context. I guess although the viewholder was getting instantiated with the right context, the whole adapter was not. Thanks for the explanation!
2. Made sure the Recycler view and Appcompat libraries are the latest versions. 
3. For testing purposes, fixed the recycler view's height to a pre-defined value. 

Could you post the code of the adapter (V3 in your snippet) as the answer so I could accept it?

Comment: Glad to hear it. Congratulations!

Answer (score 0):

Change your `LinearLayout` width, height to `wrap_content` and set your `ImageView`, `TextView` with, height to specific number.

Comment: Thanks but that does not help.